# Does the AWS ElasticSearch need web app API for integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, integration, aws-elasticsearch

Does the AWS ElasticSearch need web app API for integration?
Or I just need to setup at aws server and embed it to the website, everything handled from aws server.

Comment: AWS Elasticsearch comes with a Kibana UI but it's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, do we need to create web app api for using it, like we update index from where? Web app api or directly in aws server

Comment: To input data you do use a web API. Most web frameworks provide a way to integrate.

Comment: Your web app would be making usual get/put calls to AWS ES and the ES cluster will respond back with corresponding results.